# Get a public link in Google Cloud Storage to be only accessed using my App

Tags: android, google-cloud-storage

In my Android App I store some data in Cloud Storage and that I want only to be used by my App. So the bucket has files that have a public links everyone can access it given he has a link.

So I believe for insecurity someone may decompile or check my app requests and therefore get all the links and use them to download my data that are my app secrets OR uses the link for his own app and therefore increasing my payments.

I have to get the files using the links so as to use for third party download manager libraries to download.

I can not use `Firebase` since I think I wont get a link to use in my third party library!

How can I make the link available only using my signed application package name??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sharing a Public Link in your buckets on the Google Cloud Storage only makes the File Publicly Readable[[1]](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public). Hence, to be able to make those modifications by unauthorized users as you suggested would be a security issue not only on your application but also on the Google cloud platform as a whole.

However, if you are considering other access Control mechanisms, I recommend you read the documentation[[2]](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/).

Using a Signed URL on the other hand, gives access to read, write or delete a resource for a limited period of time[[3]](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls#signed-urls). And indeed, anyone that has access to the Signed URL can access the resource until the URL expires. However, when creating a signed URL within your application code, your program constructs a string that will be signed. You can choose to either sign this string from within your program, or from within a Google App Engine application using the App Engine Identity service using your App Engine's service account credentials[[4]](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls#signing-gae) hence, enforcing additional security with your App Engine's Service account credentials.

For an example of the way to generate a signed url for a cloud storage object in Java [see this link](https://www.quickprogrammingtips.com/google-cloud/how-to-create-google-cloud-storage-signed-url-in-java.html).

Comment: So can I generate signed url from within my Android App or using App Engine only?

Comment: Absolutely, you can generate Signed URL for your Android Application. The documentation[1] shows how you can create Signed URL from your application program. [1]https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-signed-urls-program

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and **Happy Coding!**.